# Is there a way to refer to class methods and variables without using 'this' (ES6)?

Tags: javascript

I have a large class in my application and it is becoming cumbersome to write lines of code like this:

```
this.reduceValue(this.value1 - this.value2);
```

where the 'this' object is overused to access class methods and variables.

For example, in this class

```
var subtractor = class {
    constructor(val1, val2) {
        this.value1 = val1;
        this.value2 = val2;
    }

    subtract() {
        this.value2 -= this.value1;
    }
}
```

how would I rewrite this class in a way that allows me to access `value1` and `value2` without having to use the 'this' keyword.

Comment: You can store local references like `let value = this.value;`. Or you can shorten the reference by stating `let t = this;` and use it afterwards like `t.reduceValue(t.value1 - t.value2);`

Comment: There is a way - dont use classes

Comment: What a strange suggestion @TheReason

Comment: @baao it's not a strange suggestion it's a nature of using `class`. If you decided to use it then you have to refer properties/method within this class it via `this`. Am i right?

Comment: @The Reason is correct. If you don't want to use `this` then don't use classes. JS allows you multiple ways to define class data structures. Even without using `class` itself.

Comment: How do you use this `class`? Any code examples? Probably it can be re-written in an IIFE

Answer (score 0):

check if it's desired:

```
var subtractor = class {
    constructor(...args) {
        args.forEach((x, i) => this[`value${i + 1}`] = x)
    }

    subtract() {
        this.value2 -= this.value1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not even worth the effort fam :(

Comment: So you may give your question more clear. as seems nobody understand you. because it's strange question